# Adding Filter to Portfolio Timeline

Tags: rally

I was wondering if it's possible in Rally to add a small customization to the Portfolio Timeline app by adding a filter on the Targeted Program.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for PortfolioTimeline is not available, and portfolio timeline component is not ready to be used in AppSDK.